# RStudio using kable to print a table of multiple variable sums and percentages

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I'd like to create a table using kable that knits to Word. I can create the table I want for one variable, but I'd like to present multiple variables in one table.
Data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
             rating1=c("Very important", "Important", "Unimportant", "Unimportant", "Very important", "Important"),
             rating2=c("Important", "Important", "Neutral", "Unimportant", "Unimportant", " Very unimportant"),
             rating3=c( "Unimportant", "Unimportant", " Very unimportant", "Neutral", "Unimportant", " Very unimportant"))
```

Here's what I have so far for one variable, and I'd like the same for multiple variables. But I'd like the layout to be different: variable names as rows on the left hand side, and then columns for the n and % for each of the 5 answers options (11 columns in total).

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(rating1)) %>%
  count(rating1, sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(percent = round(100 * (n / sum(n)), 1)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  add_row(rating1 = "**Total**", n = sum(.$n), percent = 100) %>%
  kable(align = "lcc", col.names = c('**Rating 1**', '**n**', '**%**'))
```

Comment: Take a look at the function `pivot_longer`

Comment: Thank you @danlooo. I am a very inexperienced coder, is there any chance you could provide more info/help with the code?

Comment: Read the free book [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)